# Is there a xml namespace convention?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, rdf

Sorry for raising another question in stack overflow.
Is there any restrictions for xml namespace?

I am using python2 rdflib to manually create a xml file.
It turns out http://domain.xxx/subdirectory/ and http://domain.xxx/subdirectory/xxx# could be a namespace in xml.
However, http://domain.xxx/subdirectory/xxx_ is not valid.
It automatically translated to namespace: http://domain.xxx/subdirectory/

Is rdflib has restriction on handle the namespace or namespace like http://domain.xxx/subdirectory/xxx_ is not a valid one.
Thanks!

Comment: As an XML namespace name, http://domain.xxx/subdirectory/xxx is perfectly valid, and should never be converted to anything else. However, RDF namespaces are not exactly the same as XML namespaces (and I'm no expert on RDF). I think you're seeing some effect that's specific to the rdflib tool, or to the way that you are using it.

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes exactly. So I am trying to have a namespace of domain.xxx/subdirectory/xxx_ (note there is a underscore at the end).

Comment: Sorry I didn't finish my comment. The first item would be like domain.xxx/subdirectory/xxx_000001. A little bit similar to domain.xxx/subdirectory/xxx#00001. However rdflib in python2 doesn't recognize this. So probably it is the way I am using the lib that causes some issue. Thanks for the new insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original [XML document definition from 1999](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#ns-decl) states

> The attribute's value, a URI reference, is the namespace name identifying the namespace. The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, should have the characteristics of uniqueness and persistence. **It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists)**.

It should suffice for the namespace (not the prefix) to be an unique string, but in this case you will usually get a warning like

> namespace warning : xmlns: URI ... is not absolute

By convention, it should be a

- **URI** (XML 1.0, [RFC3986](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)) according to the specification for [XML-1.0 namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/).
- **IRI** (XML 1.1, [RFC3987](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt)) according to the specification for [XML-1.1 namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-names11-20060816/).