# What does "ax22" refer to in XML?

Tags: xml, wsdl

I'm currently reconsidering my life choices while I integrate an ancient SOAP webservice into an existing NodeJS application.

I keep seeing `ax21`, `ax22` and `ax23` in WSDL/XML documents and I can't figure out what they mean.

Example:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:ax22="http://example.com/xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/xsd">
```

I understand that this defines a namespace but why `ax22`? Does it have any special meaning?

Google is not of much help as it keeps finding actual WSDL files and no documentation whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that this defines a namespace but why ax22?
>   Does it have any special meaning?

No. It is an arbitrary string that fulfills the requirements of a [QName (qualified name)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-qualnames), that is used as a unique identifier in the scope of the current file. For conveniance, the same identifiers are used across different files, but that is not mandatory.

The essential part that has to be unique is the [URI/IRI / the attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60678120/1305969) of the namespace.

Comment: So it's the equivalent of naming a loop variable `i`?

Comment: In a way, yes. It's a variable name restricted by some guidelines. But you can choose it freely (in the bounds of the guidelines).

Comment: Just as SO users can choose to call themselves "zx485".

Comment: I seem to recall some Apache utility that generated namespace prefixes following this kind of pattern, but it was a while ago and I don't recall the specific utility. It certainly suggests it might be a software-generated prefix.